# Destruir (delete) una matriz dentro de una clase para redimensionarla

Tags: java

Tengo una matriz bidimensional que se crea dentro de una clase de acuerdo con unos valores dados a la clase, pero el propio objeto puede requerir que la matriz se destruya y se vuelva a dimensionar, ¿Es posible destruir la matriz?

Código  de como se crea la matriz:

```
private void createArrays()
{
    final int col = 10;
    
    faces = new int[model.faces][ ];
    for (int i = 0; i < model.faces; i++)
        faces[i] = new int[col];
}
```

En C++ la destrucción de la matriz para volver a crearla sería:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.faces; i++)
    delete[] faces[i];

delete[] faces;
```

¿Es posible esto en Java?

Comment: Si quitas todas las referencias a la misma, ña JVM deberia correr el garbage collector y eliminarla. Vos solo tenes que ocuparte de no dejar referencias huerfanas...

Comment: No necesitas "destruir" y volver a dimensionar. Simplemente reasignala y el GC de java se encargará de borrar cualquier objeto que ya no tenga referencias. De todas maneras, si necesitas cambiar a menudo el tamaño del array lo mismo necesitas usar otra estructura que no sea un array, como una lista por ejemplo.

Comment: Por si quieres indagar un poco más. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java no controlas el tiempo de vida de las variables. Simplemente creas una instancia nueva y cuando el recolector de basura vea que no hay más referencias a un objeto, liberará la memoria.

En Java tampoco existen los punteros y `new int[model.faces][ ]` no crea un arreglo de punteros. Simplemente usa `new int[n][m]`.

No intentes transferir tus conocimientos de C++ a Java. Solo te confundirás.

En Java todas las variables contienen referencias a objetos (como si fuera un puntero en C++), a excepción de los tipos primitivos. [Los arreglos también son objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html).